# Rendering a non trivial {{view}}

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have some `view` helpers, for example:

```
App.ChannelIconView = Ember.View.extend({

    render: function(buffer) {
        var channel = this.get('channel');
        var icon = App.getChannelIcon(channel);
        return buffer.push(icon + ' ' + channel);
    }
});
```

Which I use like this, in a template:

```
{{view App.ChannelIconView channelBinding="properties.channel"}}
```

Now I would like to define a more complex view. I would like the view to use a given handlebars template, instead of pushing a complex html to the handlebars buffer. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just use the property `templateName` on a [View](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html):

```
App.ChannelIconView = Ember.View.extend({
   templateName : "yourTemplate"
});

{{view App.ChannelIconView channelBinding="properties.channel"}}
```

Comment: Thanks. Added a link to the documentation. Somehow I missed that part :(